# Is there any way to add different background color in React big calendar for entire date cell only when there is any event displayed on cell?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-big-calendar

Currently I am trying to use this below:

```js
const ColoredDateCellWrapper = ({ children, value }) =>
  React.cloneElement(Children.only(children), {
    style: {
      ...children.style,
      backgroundColor: value < CURRENT_DATE ? "lightgreen" : "lightblue",
    },
  })
```

but it won't work for me as I need to add different `backgroundColor` for the cells having events array.

Answer (score 0):

Yes in eventStyleGetter you can return the class name and  provide the background color to the cell where events are there.

Comment: please feel free to write some code in your answer to illustrate what you mean

Comment: Yes Sure we can use eventStyleGetter in this way const eventStyleGetter = ( start, isSelected) => {
    var style = {
     //whatever styles you wana give
    };
    return {
      className:  "yourclassname",
      style: style,
    };
  }; and then in your component you can use this eventPropGetter={eventStyleGetter} way.

Comment: i would be able to help more if you could post what are you passing to your calendar component